# Swift reload collection view with button click not works

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to swift. I used [LTBA components](https://github.com/bhlvoong/LBTAComponents) to build swift app. I follow some tutorial to develop social application like twitter. I start implement to follow button functions. its call the the another API call but same response come with minor modification(e.g - number of follower property increase by one). call also perfectly working. but collection view did not reload.my code is.

**ViewConroller**

```
import LBTAComponents
import TRON
import SwiftyJSON

class HomeDatasourceController: DatasourceController {
    let errorMessageLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Apologies something went wrong. Please try again later..."
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.isHidden = true
        return label
    }()

    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }

    func follow(){
        print("inside controller")
        Service.sharedInstance.fetchfollowHomeFeed { (homeDatasource, err) in
            if let err = err {
                self.errorMessageLabel.isHidden = false
                if let apiError = err as? APIError<Service.JSONError> {
                    if apiError.response?.statusCode != 200 {
                    self.errorMessageLabel.text = "Status code was not 200"
                    }
                }
                return
            }
            self.datasource = homeDatasource
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(errorMessageLabel)
        errorMessageLabel.fillSuperview() //LBTA method call

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 232, g: 236, b: 241)

        setupNavigationBarItems()

        Service.sharedInstance.fetchHomeFeed { (homeDatasource, err) in
            if let err = err {
                self.errorMessageLabel.isHidden = false

                if let apiError = err as? APIError<Service.JSONError> {

                    if apiError.response?.statusCode != 200 {
                        self.errorMessageLabel.text = "Status code was not 200"
                    }
                }

                return
            }

            self.datasource = homeDatasource
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        //first section of users
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            guard let user = self.datasource?.item(indexPath) as? User else { return .zero }

            let estimatedHeight = estimatedHeightForText(user.bioText)
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedHeight + 66)
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            //our tweets size estimation

            guard let tweet = datasource?.item(indexPath) as? Tweet else { return .zero }

            let estimatedHeight = estimatedHeightForText(tweet.message)

            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedHeight + 74)
        }


        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    }

    private func estimatedHeightForText(_ text: String) -> CGFloat {
        let approximateWidthOfBioTextView = view.frame.width - 12 - 50 - 12 - 2
        let size = CGSize(width: approximateWidthOfBioTextView, height: 1000)
        let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]

        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)

        return estimatedFrame.height
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        if section == 1 {
            return .zero
        }
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        if section == 1 {
            return .zero
        }
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 64)
    }
}
```

**DataCell**

```
import LBTAComponents

class UserCell: DatasourceCell {

    override var datasourceItem: Any? {
        didSet {
            guard let user = datasourceItem as? User else { return }
            followButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(follow), for: .touchUpInside)
            nameLabel.text = user.name
            usernameLabel.text = user.username
            bioTextView.text = user.bioText

            profileImageView.loadImage(urlString: user.profileImageUrl)
        }
    }

    let profileImageView: CachedImageView = {
        let imageView = CachedImageView()
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile_image")
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Brian Voong"
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return label
    }()

    let usernameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "@buildthatapp"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.textColor = UIColor(r: 130, g: 130, b: 130)
        return label
    }()

    let bioTextView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "iPhone, iPad, iOS Programming Community. Join us to learn Swift, Objective-C and build iOS apps!"
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return textView
    }()

    let followButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.layer.borderColor = twitterBlue.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.setTitleColor(twitterBlue, for: .normal)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "follow"), for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -8, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        //        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets
        return button
    }()
    func follow(){
        print("inside source")
        var link = HomeDatasourceController()
        link.follow()
    }
    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        backgroundColor = .white

        separatorLineView.isHidden = false
        separatorLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 230, g: 230, b: 230)

        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        addSubview(usernameLabel)
        addSubview(bioTextView)
        addSubview(followButton)

        profileImageView.anchor(self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 12, leftConstant: 12, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 50, heightConstant: 50)

        nameLabel.anchor(profileImageView.topAnchor, left: profileImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: followButton.leftAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 12, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 20)

        usernameLabel.anchor(nameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: nameLabel.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nameLabel.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 20)

        bioTextView.anchor(usernameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: usernameLabel.leftAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: -4, leftConstant: -4, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

        followButton.anchor(topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 12, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 12, widthConstant: 120, heightConstant: 34)
    }
}
```

It using LBTA components.i tried self.collectionView?.reloadData() but its not reloaded. Please help me to fix this problem.Please help me to figure out this problem

Comment: Any one find the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are using a closure in the **follow()** method so you need to write the code for reloading, in the main queue.

**write your reload code in follow like this**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I already with `DispatchQueue.main.async` but it is not worked. i hope, i missed some thing with LBTA components

Comment: Where are you incrementing the number of followers? you should call reload after you increment it.

Comment: `fetchfollowHomeFeed` is the api call that is give the list of data in that data has increased number.My actual problem is i can see the result viewDidLoad is render.not in button click.

Comment: write dump(self.datasource) before reload to check if datasource is set properly only then you can be sure that data is set but view isn't rendering. API call is giving the data I know but make sure that data is perfectly set to the datasource.

Comment: i'm sure it is set inside the follow function `self.datasource = homeDatasource`

Comment: print the values or attache debugger or dump the values to recheck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `completion handler` for the `follow` method:

```
func follow(completionHandler: @escaping (Any, NSError?) -> ()){
    Service.sharedInstance.fetchfollowHomeFeed { (homeDatasource, err) in
        do {
            // handle the response from the api call
            completionHandler(homeDatasource, nil)

        }  catch let err{
            self.errorMessageLabel.isHidden = false
            if let apiError = err as? APIError<Service.JSONError> {
                if apiError.response?.statusCode != 200 {
                self.errorMessageLabel.text = "Status code was not 200"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call your method like:

```
self.follow() {homeDatasource,error in
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried but no luck. Its not reload my collection view.